# What is the structure in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement

> In what is one of Europe’s biggest accounting scandals in recent years, Wirecard acknowledged the money was phantom after two banks in the Philippines where it supposedly had been deposited denied having ever received it.

First of all, in a single sentence where used a connector "where" but used too many subject and finite verb. How this type of sentence is constructed. And how I relate subject- verb agreement?

Comment: "Where it supposedly had been deposited denied having ever received it" is a relative clause modifying "Phillipines".

Comment: No. Only _where it supposedly had been deposited_ is the relative clause, and it modifies _two banks in the Philippines_..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where doesn't tie the whole sentence together; it's actually just part of a clause in the sentence: "where it supposedly had been deposited". Below is how I parse the whole sentence:

---

First off, the part before the first comma,

> In what is one of Europe’s biggest accounting scandals in recent years,

is a separate clause modifying the rest of the sentence, so we can just look at the rest:

> Wirecard acknowledged the money was phantom after two banks in the Philippines where it supposedly had been deposited denied having ever received it.

Grammatically there's actually more than one way to understand this, but I think one way makes more sense, so I'll try to explain that one.

When I read it and get to the part "had been deposited **denied** having", the word "denied" sticks out to me, because it doesn't fit with the verb phrase "had been deposited". So that tells me that "deposited" ends its clause. In fact we can (and I personally would) add commas to separate out that clause:

> Wirecard acknowledged the money was phantom after two banks in the Philippines, where it supposedly had been deposited, denied having ever received it.

And then we can look at the grammar of the rest of the sentence without that clause. Another clause that can be separated out is the one with "after". It modifies "acknowledged", telling us when that happened:

> two banks [ in the Philippines ] denied [ having ever received it ]

And once we take out the "after" clause, we're left with

> Wirecard acknowledged [ the money was phantom ]